# FabricJS IText (and Textbox) is not editable in React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to include a canvas in my React Bootstrap component, but I have a problem with IText and Textbox. Even if I set the corresponding property, I can not edit the text in the box. I can drag it, resize it, and even double click to insert the cursor, but I can not delete or change the text. This is my code:

```
const TestCanvas = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas-test");
    let text = new fabric.IText('Test', {evented: true, selectable: true, editable: true});
    text.onInput = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    text.onSelect = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    canvas.add(text);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  return (
      <canvas id={"canvas-test"} />
  )

}
```

As you can see, I tried to set the onInput handler, but it does not fire. On the other hand, the onSelect event fires on every mousedown.

EDIT: Turns out that it doesn't work because I placed it in a Modal. For some reason Modal blocks the onInput event. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Modal steals focus. I added `enforceFocus={false}` to its properties and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem except I am using vue 3 and ionic-framework 6.

I was also trying to edit a fabric iText inside of a modal `ion-modal` and the focus was being stolen from the `textarea`

My solution was setting `backdropBreakpoint=1` on the `ion-modal`.